# BIND9 One Server Two sub-domains

Tags: networking, apache2, dns

I'm sure this should be simple but I can't get a single server to serve DNS for two sub-domains. When I do nslookup for DNSserver it correctly resolves, but the other servers do not resolve, despite being PING each other.

Here is my setup

```
DNSServer.example.org 192.168.252.22
Server1.cnc.example.org 192.168.252.21
Server2.report.example.org 192.168.252.20
```

[named.conf.local file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwyQQ.png)

Main domain forward lookup zone configuration below:

[example.org file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbQhd.png)

sub domain forward lookup zone configuration below:

[cnc.example.org file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xkon.png)

sub domain forward lookup zone configuration below:

[report.example.org file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRE0a.png)

reverse lookup zone configuration below

[reverse file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjPye.png)

The other two reverse lookup zones are very similar.

Any help greatly appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second two subdomains don't need to be served as different zones.  You should be able to have only the zone for example.org - you seem to have enough info in that zone file already to serve the subdomains as well.  There is some redundancy in your config that will be cleaned up if you do that.  Not sure what the answer to your question is, can you post the response to queries for the second two?  You're doing A lookups on all three and the second two it responds NXDOMAIN?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply Thomas. When I do nslookup on DNSServer it works fine, when I do nslookup on server1 I get a message saying  ** server can't find Server1: SERVFAIL

Comment: What do you get if you remove all the zones in your named.conf except the initial example.org zone (and possibly the reverse lookup zones), and comment out the "delegated zones" NS records in the example.org zone file, leaving the A records for server1 and server2?

Comment: Hi I get the same meesage ** server can't find Server1: SERVFAIL message and checking on server1 it can no longer resolve DNSServer now

Comment: Hi in addition if you I do server1.cnc.example.org it correctly finds the IP address